# Qt and Intel Perceptual SDK

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries, intel

I'm currently developping an application to recognize hand gestures and I use the **Intel Perceptual SDK** to track the hands. I want to develop a graphical interface using **Qt** but I'm unable to configure **VS2010** in order to make these two libraries working well.

The **Intel Perceptual SDK** is provided with prebuilt static runtime libraries (flags /MT and /MTd) but **Qt** uses dynamic runtime libraries (flags /MD and MDd). I don't know how can I use **Intel Perceptual SDK** with dynamic runtime libraries. There is an explanation in [the documenation](http://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/perceptual_computing/documentation/html/index.html?devguide_project_settings.html) but I don't understand this one.

Can you help me ?

Thanks,

Flavien

Comment: What is specific about the IP SDK? I would say you can just use `LIBS += -L/path/to/your/static/lib -lstaticlibname` as usual. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

The explanation you find is exactly what you need and also what Laszlo Papp is saying.
Just grab the .props file corresponding of what you need/want (you will find them within the PCSDK under `[install directory]/Intel/PCSDK/props`) and you will also find a README file inside that folder.
Hope it's help, and if not, come back!